# Return value in stored procedure MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql

What I am looking to do now is to return a value in C# 
    indicating that the stored procedure has completed. I was 
    thinking of doing something like this within the last MYSQL 
    stored procedure to be called:

```
    int status =0 
    if (proc.result >0) 
    then { status = proc.result } 
    label.status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ExecuteNonQuery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-executenonquery) will return an int which indicates how the Stored Procedure completed.

Get return value from stored procedure:

```
var returnValue = new SqlParameter("returnVal", SqlDbType.Int);
returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
command.Parameters.Add(returnValue);
```

Comment: So, reading that page you linked, ExecuteNonQuery concatenates the result and I don't need to insert the if then in the stored procedure, right?

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery will return the number of row affected by the operation.

Comment: That's great, but I'm look to simply return 0 from the stored procedure if it was successful and 1 in the case that it wasn't successful.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to the fail fast system where when something fails I'm notified, if it's successful I'm notified. Getting the result that rows have been changed is not what I'm looking to do.

Comment: You should just throw an exception in the stored procedure on failure. If you really need to see the return value then use a parameter.

Comment: edit that into your questions. It's illegible in the comments.